# jQuery Cycle Plugin - Change Pager Anchors to Weekdays

Tags: jquery, cycle

I want to create a menu that sorts by days. Everything works except the pager won't output weekdays. My code is as follows:

```
 var days = new Array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday" ); 
$('#main') 
.before('<div id="nav">') 
.cycle({ 
    fx:     'toss', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '#nav',
    options:    {
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i,el) {
            return '<a href="#">'+document.write(days[i+1])+'</a>';
        }
    }
});
```

It still defaults to numbers, however.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You have three errors. First, don't use `document.write` inline, second, you are nesting an extra `options` element. The whole thing passed to the `cycle` call are the options. Third, both `idx` and your array are zero indexed, so no need for the `+ 1` :

```
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]; 
$('#main') 
  .before('<div id="nav">') 
  .cycle({ 
      fx:     'toss', 
      timeout: 0, 
      pager:  '#nav',
      pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i,el) {
          return '<a href="#">'+days[i]+'</a>';
      }
  });
```